# Filter posts tags by wordpress api

Tags: wordpress, api, wordpress-rest-api

I created a post-type called `"material"`, with taxonomies of type tags called `"ano"`. I'm trying to filter through the wordpress rest api a specific value for that `"ano (years)"`, but it doesn't work, it returns all posts, including those that don't have the specific tag.

```
<?php

$url = 'https://cat.site.com/wp-json/wp/v2/material?filter[taxonomy]=ano&filter[term]=1994';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response = json_decode($response);
var_dump($response);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I used the tag ID:

```
https://cat.site.com/wp-json/wp/v2/material?ano=28
```